# How to override page.tlp.php

Tags: 7

I am trying to style a page I made, the url to the page is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:13080/nieuws
```

I copied page.tlp.php to my template folder and renamed it page--nieuws.tlp.php and adapted the file but the changes don't come through. I also flush all cache every time.

I tried to add this to my template.php (found it on this website) but it still doesn't work, could anyone help me out?

```
function asap_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'nieuws') {
    // This will look for template named page--nieuws.tpl.php in your theme.
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__nieuws';
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick spelling lesson - In the word `template`, does the `l` come before the `p` or is it the other way round? With that in mind can you spot the problem with your file names?

Comment: Holy f I can't believe I made such a stupid typo, thanks a bunch, really sorry

Comment: No need to apologise - I for one wouldn't be able to call myself a programmer if something like that didn't happen at least once a week ;).

Comment: @editors Please stop trying to correct the spelling of `.tlp` in this question. That is the cause of the OP's issue, if you correct it then the question no longer makes sense.